# Why is this code resulting in bool(false)?

Tags: php, sql

The below code, checks in my folder 'mysqls' for .sql files. Then I want it to execute the .sqls into the database.

```
<?php
$dirf = 'mysqls';
$dir = scandir($dirf);
unset($dir['0']);
unset($dir['1']);
foreach($dir as $file) {
    $sql = file_get_contents($file);
    $qr = $dbh->exec($sql);
}
?>
```

I've used die(var_dump($sql)); although it comes up with bool(false)
The code finds all the files that have the .sql extension successfully, although it does not execute it.

Comment: `echo $file;` -- does it output the filename correctly?

Comment: @AmalMurali Yes, it comes up with `hey.sqlINSERT INTO 'test' ('id', 'title', 'test') VALUES ('1', 'hehe', 'testing');`

Comment: Are you sure? I'm asking about the output of `$file`, not `$sql`.

Comment: i believe in order to work your sql file must contain only one sql statement, if you have multiple, it will fail.

Comment: @Twisted1919 I've only got one .SQL file in my folder.

Comment: @AmalMurali Actually wait, sorry. Must have had another code in there to grab the sql. But yes it only says 'hey.sql' which is the name of the file.

Answer (score 1):

You have to add the directory for file_get_contents():

```
$sql = file_get_contents($dirf . '/'. $file);
```

Comment: It gets the files already.. and it does work. As i've tested die(var_dump($dirl)); and it came up with the file names. So yes it is already reading the files. Its the executing into the database thats wrong.

Comment: Well, that's another question. Set PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE to PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION, and you'll see the error. `$dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);`

Comment: It dosnt show an error. It shows `INSERT INTO 'test' ('id', 'title', 'test') VALUES ('1', 'hehe', 'testing');`

Comment: ?? If your talking about where I placed  `$dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);` I placed it under $qr = $dbh->exec($sql);

Comment: That's wrong, you have to set it before. Place it above the foreach loop. It's not what will output error, it will only tell PDO to throw an exception in case of error.

Comment: I have tried this and it just comes up with a blank screen. Ill turn my PHP errors on and try.

Comment: I end up getting it to work. Would you know how I would be able to read from multiple folders inside that the folder called 'mysqls'. So for example theres two folders in 'mysqls' with .sqls in it. How would I be able to make them get read?

Comment: You can use `glob()` instead of scandir. This function allows for wildcards, so you can use `glob('mysqls/*/*.sql')`. The output will be without `.` and `..` entries.

Comment: To get it working I had to change  `$sql = file_get_contents($file); `into `$sql = file_get_contents($dirf . '/*/'. $file);` How would I use glob?

Comment: Now I see you can't use glob because the subdirectory information is lost. So you have to recursively scan the directories. But this is another problem, unrelated to original question. I consider this thread closed.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41419/discussion-between-user3001214-and-marek)

Comment: Can we move this over to chat?

Comment: If not what would my next question to ask be?

Comment: Try to get it done yourself, only once you have a problem, ask.

Comment: Yeah well I still need help,